# jQuery UI 1.9 popup: how to check is popup?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

[jQuery UI 1.9 milestone 6](http://view.jqueryui.com/master/demos/popup/default.html): how to check current state - is popup or not?

Thanks!

**EDITED**

This doesn't work...

```
$(function() {
    $("#login-form").popup();
    if($('.ui-popup').attr('aria-expanded')=='true') $('#aa').style.background='red';
    else $('#aa').style.background='white';
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution of this problem:

```
$(function(){
    $("#login-form").popup({
        open: function(){
            document.getElementById('login-menu').style.backgroundColor='#fff';
        },
        close: function(){
            document.getElementById('login-menu').style.backgroundColor='#000';
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: If you aren't planning to accept my answer to the question in the title, you should at least mark your own as accepted so others know you've found a solution.

Comment: In 2 hours I will be able to do that

Answer (score 1):

Based on your demo page:

```
$('.ui-popup').attr('aria-expanded')
```

will return string 'true' or 'false'.

Comment: This is how you get the state of the popup, I'm not really sure from your edit what you want to do with that info. Do you have a specific event that should trigger the test and the `hide()` logic?

Comment: I want change background color of "log in" text depending on popup state. show() and hide() are only examples.

Comment: Based on the demo, it looks like `popup` requires 'open' or 'close' as an argument.